# Getting displacement data from acceleration in matlab

Tags: matlab

Im working on a project right now using arduino and im stuck,i didn't find a way to get the displacement data from the data i get from the 3-axis accelerometer im using this code:

```
    clear all, clc
%delete(arduino)
com='COM_31';
delete(instrfind({'Port'},{com}));
arduino=serial(com,'BaudRate',9600); 
fopen(arduino);  
while(1)
 donnee=fscanf(arduino,'%f\t %f\t %f'),  
 x=data(1); y=data(2) ;z=data(3),
 plot3(x,y,z)
 hold on
end  
fclose(arduino);
```

is there a simple way i can achieve this and plot the result in 3D
thanks,

Answer (score 0):

If you declare three vectors from the start and fill them with your measured data you can plot the whole trajectory.

```
clear all; clc
%delete(arduino)
com='COM_31';
delete(instrfind({'Port'},{com}));
arduino=serial(com,'BaudRate',9600); 
fopen(arduino);  
fig=figure(1);clf;
x=0;y=0;z=0;
vx=0;vy=0;vz=0;
tic
while(1)
 data=fscanf(arduino,'%f\t %f\t %f');
 dt = toc;tic;
 vx=vx+dt*data(1); 
 vy=vx+dt*data(2);
 vz=vz+dt*data(3);
 x(end+1)=x(end)+vx*dt;
 y(end+1)=y(end)+vy*dt;
 z(end+1)=z(end)+vz*dt;
 plot3(x,y,z)
end  
fclose(arduino);
```

Comment: thanks for your answer,the problem here is that the data im getting is acceleration so it need to be integrated twice to get the displacement and then plot it .

Comment: maybe tic toc in the loop so you know the execution time?

Comment: I added a conversion from a -> v -> x